# Signal Handling to Ensure Destructors are Called in C++

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have a class with constructor and destructor. Let's call that class as Student.

Suppose there is some code

```
{
    //some code
    Student student;
    //signal , may be ctrl+c or any other signal

}
```

What I want is when signal is thrown, I still want the destructor of student object to be called.

I have some basics knowledge of signals but I don't know how to do this.

I know this can be specific to o/s; I am trying for Linux.

Comment: @Scheff signal handling is a part of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done easily in C++.

You need to [handle the signal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal). The handler needs to inform the program about the event. The program needs to react by shutting down cleanly (this is most often done by throwing an exception; naturally your program must exercise exception safety for this to work).

The problem lies in the inform—react sequence. There is no good way of doing this. According to the standard, the *only* thing a signal handker is permitted to do is to set a global variable of type `sig_atomic_t` and return. Consequently, the program must check the value of that variable *periodically* and react when its value is changed.

Some operating systems may allow more things that are safe to do in an exception handler. Throwing a C++ exception, however, isn't normally one of those things. Signals are asynchronous in nature. If one is delivered when an object is in the middle of construction, throwing an exception is likely to leave its state inconsistent.

So just about the only way is to insert checks everywhere in the program, or perhaps if it has a centralised IO or event loop, insert a check there.

Comment: A commonly used technique is to have a pipe open to yourself that the signal hndler writes a byte into and the main event loop reads..

Comment: @JesperJuh how is this better than setting and checking a global?

Comment: It's better because with a global you have to busy loop to continuously check it. With a pipe you can stay blocked in `select`, `poll`, `epoll` etc while waiting for the pipe to become ready for reading.

Comment: @JesperJuhl no I don't. I check *after* a regular IO op, not in a busy wait loop.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN according to the standard also call `std::quick_exit`. You need to register some cleanup function with `std::at_quick_exit`. As an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class K
{
public:
    K(const char* _name)
    : name(_name)
    { cout << "K() for " << name << endl; registered.emplace(this); }
    ~K()
    { cout << "~K() for " << name << endl; registered.erase(this); }

    static void cleanup()
    {
        for (auto i: registered) {
            i->~K();
        }
    }

private:
    const char* name= nullptr;
    static set<K*> registered;
};
set<K*> K::registered;

extern "C"
void signalHandler(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    if (sig == SIGKILL || sig == SIGTERM || sig == SIGINT) {
        quick_exit(1);
    }
    return;
}

K k1("global k1");

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction= signalHandler;
    act.sa_flags= SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    for (int i= 0; i < 64; i++) {
        sigaction(i, &act, nullptr);
    }

    K k2("local k2");
    at_quick_exit(K::cleanup);
    for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "." << flush;
        sleep(1);
    }
    cout << "Normal exit" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that set will not preserve the order of deinitialization, you could use a list for that matter.